# Project : error PRJ0050: Failed to register output

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

When I use Visual Studio 2008 on my XP, everything is fine. But when I use the same on my Vista, I always get this error message when compiling my Visual C++ project. How to fix this?

```
1>Project : error PRJ0050: Failed to register output.  Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try launching visual studio with "Run as administrator" options.  (Right-click->Run as administrator)

If that doesn't work, run dependency walker (depends.exe) on your DLL to see if anything is missing and try registering from an elevated command prompt using:

```
 regsvr32 mydll.dll
```

regsvr32.exe should give more information about the failure.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue. Lines of investigation included User account controls, Disable Registration and missing Dependencies.

My issue was resolved when looking into output registration. Go to: Properties-> Linker -> General -> Register Output. Set this to No. You will need to do this for debug and release configurations.
This fixed my problem.